# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

```
    function addRole(val)
    {

   if (val == "ADD NEW") 

    {

    $('#RoleModal').modal('show');
    $('#form_role').validate({
            rules:  {
                       Storage Code: { required: true},
                       Storage Location: { required: true},
                    },
            messages:{
                       Storage Code: {required: "This field is Required"},
                       Storage Location: {required: "This field is Required"}
                    }
       }); 
    }
}
```

This is my JavaScript code,But this throws a Javascript error 
**ReferenceError: addRole is not defined**
while i defined that function

**This is my View Code**

```
echo form_dropdown('Birth_Certificate_Storage_id['.$key.']', $optionstorage,"",array('class'=>'form-control roleId','id'=>'Birth_Certificate_Storage_id['.$key.']','onchange'=>'addRole(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)'));
 /* second line for readability  */
```

Comment: addRole() seems to have a syntax error, so it won't define itself... quote keys names w/space

Comment: If you want to have spaces in object property names, you have to surround them with quotes, like that: `"Storage Code": { required: true},`

Answer (score 2):

corrected code, use the quotes for string keys with  space...

```
   function addRole(val)
    {

   if (val == "ADD NEW") 

    {

    $('#RoleModal').modal('show');
    $('#form_role').validate({
            rules:  {
                       "Storage Code": { required: true},
                       "Storage Location": { required: true},
                    },
            messages:{
                       "Storage Code": {required: "This field is Required"},
                       "Storage Location": {required: "This field is Required"}
                    }
       }); 
    }
}
```